# Is there an elegant way in SQL Server to insert a string in any place within another string - including the end?

Tags: sql-server, string

My scenario is that I want to dynamically insert some constant string value into another dynamically defined string. If a particular substring is present at the very end of the dynamic string, I want to insert the constant string immediately prior to that substring. If that substring is not present at the end of the dynamic string, the constant string should be concatenated to the end.

It is not safe to assume in my case that the substring can only occur once in the dynamic string.

The annoying thing I've run into is that STUFF is 1-indexed and returns NULL if you specify a "start" value greater than the length of the string. Which means that you can't use STUFF to concatenate the constant string to the very end of the dynamic string. If you could, that would seem about optimal, unless I'm missing something.

My current best version of this code is equivalent to the following. This produces the correct results.

```
DECLARE @Substring nvarchar(max) = '[substring]';
DECLARE @ConstantString nchar(1) = '*';

SELECT
    IIF
        (RIGHT(d.DynamicString, LEN(@Substring)) = @Substring
        ,STUFF(d.DynamicString, LEN(d.DynamicString) + 1 - LEN(@Substring), 0, @ConstantString)
        ,CONCAT(d.DynamicString, @ConstantString))
FROM
    (VALUES
    /*Example input*/
        ('abcdfg[substring]')
        ,('hijklmnop')
        ,('[substring]xyz')
    ) d (DynamicString)
```

Output of the above:

```
abcdfg*[substring]
hijklmnop*
[substring]xyz*
```

Can this be improved upon? I've considered that I could get around the STUFF limitation by reversing the dynamic string and doing everything backwards, then reversing it back, but in my judgement that wouldn't reduce the overall complexity.

Comment: Please put sample input and sample output, to give more clarity on what you expect

Comment: The input is coded into the VALUES structure for easy testing - I've marked it with a comment to make that more clear. I've added the output that this produces.

Comment: You could add a character on the end of the string, and remove it afterwards. Probably no less complex

Comment: @Charlieface - that's the sort of clever thing I was thinking might be possible. It's a good idea, and would be decent as an answer to this question if you want to post it as one. For my scenario where I don't use the capability of STUFF to override parts of the text (which would break this as a solution), that should work great. As you say, not necessarily less complex, but it's definitely a way of eliminating the "switch" like element from the code. All cases can then be handled by the same code path. Might be interesting to benchmark this and see if it performs better because of that.